# ubuntu 12.10 amd drivers

Tags: ati, 12.10

I installed ubuntu 12.10 the entire HDD Fresh, and everything is ok, but i noticed additonal drivers

circle with green--[Advanced Mirco Device [AMD] nee at:cedar PRO [Radeon HD 5450/6350]
the device is using the recommended driver.

[checked] using X.Org x server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)

[uncheck] using video driver for the amd graphic accelerators from fglrx propertery

[uncheck] same the above and fglrx-updates

is ok with Checked? i wants to know, thanks

Comment: My two cents: OS/version Ubuntu 12.10 lspci | grep VGA: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar PRO [Radeon HD 5450/6350] The proprietary drivers are not had to get, but they do indeed suck, big time.
At least in a dual display configuration.
I've tried both the other alternatives after buying a 27" Samsung monitor (2560x1440) and using it together with the old 24" BenQ (1920x1080) monitor. With the proprietary I could only get the highest resolution on the Samsung if the monitor was rotated!!?? In 1920x1080, (the only alternative) everything was also much

Comment: 12.10 is unsupported, why are you installing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfect how it is now. From experience, I can tell you that if the open source drivers work good automatically, use them. The proprietary drivers, fglrx, are hard to get working most of the time. You will be saving yourself a lot of trouble by sticking with what works.

You should leave it like this:

[image]

Comment: Same as Nvidia?

Comment: Yes, use the Additional Drivers program, and if the open source Nvidia drivers work, use those. Nvidia's proprietary drivers seem to work much better than ATI/AMD's, so feel free to try them as well. But for AMD, stick with the open source drivers, it's much more simple. Mark my answer as being correct if it helped you.

Comment: Wow, i think 12.10 is much better than 12.04, hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx` (add fglrx-pxpress if you have a Hybrid system with iGPU and dGPU)

Then restart the computer and run:

```
sudo amdcccle
```

The official drivers always work better.